# How to get hierarchal results from models

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have hierarchal django model and it looks like this

```
class Organizator(Model):
  is_active = models.BooleanField()
  user = models.IntegerField()
  

clas Task(Model):
  content = models.CharField()
  task_id = models.IntegerField()
  parent = models.ForeignKey('self')
  organizator = models.ForeignKey(Organizator, related_name='control_taks')
  
  
class Performer(Model):
  user = models.IntegerField()
  task = models.ForeignKey(Task, related_name='tasks')
```

from this given model I am going to get following result like this

```
{
  "user": 1,
  "is_active": true,
  "control_taks": [
    {
        "task_id": 2,
        "content": "test",
        "performers": [
            {
                "user": 1,
                "tasks": [
                    {
                        "task_id": 3,
                        "performers": [
                            {
                                "user": 3,
                                "tasks": []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

how can I do this? My code does not return expected result so I did not show here. Any help would be appreciated!